# How to send String[] from Thymeleaf multiple select form to Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a template with a form:

```
<h2>Favorite States</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/states}" name="states" method="post">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width: 60%">
        <option th:each="state: ${states}"  th:utext="${state.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to get a String[] back from this form, for example if user selected NY, CA, MA states, I want to get `String[] selectedStates = {"NY", "CA", "MA"};` in my post map Controller. How can I do that?
I have tried

```
@GetMapping(path="/states")
    public @ResponseBody String statesList (@RequestParam String[] name) {
    }
```

But it says required parameter is not received.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the javascript array to `JSON` using below code.

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```

And in controller, accept it as String parameter and then convert it back to array using Jackson library as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String [] array = mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[].class):
```

Comment: I can get the a url quering string back from the html now, but how can I turn this string into json? The string I got is something like states=NY&state=LA. Not a json string

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it and pass as a model attribute

Comment: Is there any method like `model.getAttribute("states", states)` in Spring?

Comment: And how can I wrap it as a model? Thank you!

Comment: yes, check docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html